# Struggling with loops

Tags: loops

I am very bad with coding and I don't understand loops. Is anyone able to help me with shortening my code?

```
if (correct > 0 && correct < 5) {
  score = 3;
}
if (correct > 4 && correct < 7) {
  score = 2;
}
if (correct > 6 && correct < 9) {
  score = 1;
}
if (correct > 8 && correct < 11) {
  score = 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to Learn about `switch` statement

Comment: kinda needed a loop but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the language, so, let's assume that you have two arrays of int, like this:

```
int start[4] = {0, 4, 6, 8};
int end[4] = {5, 7, 9, 11};

You can do something like this:

int score = -1;
int i = 0;

while (index > 0) {
    if ((correct > start[i]) && (correct < end[i])) score = 3 - i++;
}
```